# Jasmine unit testing, issue with .subscribe on ActivatedRoute

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-ui-router

**Background**: We recently upgraded to angular 6, we are using RXJS 6.1.0, rxjs-compat 6.1.0, and jasmine-core 2.99.1. Our tests had been broken for a bit, so im not sure when this test started to fail.

**Issue**: Whenever I go to run the unit test, i got this error on the first test.

```
TypeError: this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe is not a function
```

**Preface**: Now, when you use the below code segment. It creates a mockRoute with the value of paramMap as a function. It is supposed to have the function return the value specified, in this case an Observable of type Number.

component.spec.ts

```
mockRoute = jasmine.createSpyObj('mockRoute', ['paramMap']);
(<any>mockRoute.paramMap).and.returnValue(of({ orderId }));
sut = new ContractSchedulesComponent(<Store<AppState>><any>mockStore, 
      actions, mockRoute, null);
sut.ngOnInit();
```

Here is the code segment that it is failing on:

component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    const routeSub = this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap => {
            this.orderId = paramMap['params']['orderId'];
```

I know that it is failing because paramMap is a function and subscribe does not work on a function, even though it is supposed to return an Observable via the unit test.

Curious if this is maybe a bug between jasmine and the newer version of RXJS. But maybe i have done something wrong and i just cant see it. Would appreciate any help you guys could give. Also, if you need more insight into any of the code i can post more. Thanks!

Comment: Please give a [mcve] that shows how this all fits together. Also I'd recommend using the standard TestBed approach to wiring up and injecting dependencies, rather than newing up the class under test yourself. But yes, the broad problem is that `paramMap` is just a property of the route, not a method, so `and.returnValue` isn't an appropriate way of mocking it. Your mock must match the real thing it's replacing; `mockRoute = { paramMap: of({ orderId ])};`, perhaps.

Comment: Thank you Jon, i went ahead and mocked out the whole ActivatedRoute object and that seemed to get rid of the error.